# awk syntax error when creating an array

Tags: awk

I'm just trying to get started writing an awk script to test for inclusion in an array, however I seem to have a basic syntax error someplace.

```
#!/bin/bash


awk \
BEGIN {'myarray["foo"] = "bar" '} \
{' \
  print "$1" \
'} $1
```

If I take out the `BEGIN` line, then indeed the rest of the script works.

I have also tried it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk \
{' \
  myarray["foo"] = "bar" \
  print "$1" \
'} $1
```

Here's the error I'm getting.

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>>  <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

Comment: not clear why you're doing `{'myarray....'}`. Normally you should just surround the whole awk script with one set of single quotes like `awk 'BEGIN{ ...} { ..... } END {...}` file > outFile`. You can  get fancy with dbl-quotes to all allow shell vars to be visible, but @FredrikPihl 's advice is good. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v param="$1" '
BEGIN { myarray["foo"] = "bar"}
{
  print myarray["foo"]
  print param
}' $1
```

`-v` is the proper way to pass an variable into awks-domain:

```
-v var=val
       --assign var=val
              Assign  the  value  val to the variable var, before execution of
              the program begins.  Such variable values are available  to  the
              BEGIN block of an AWK program.
```

Example:

```
$ echo 1 > one_line_file

$ ./t.sh one_line_file 
bar
one_line_file
```